Having Issue Running Postgres Typeorm Migration in my Nestjs hybrid app microservice setup
Here is my Error Message
 yarn migration:run

> core-connect-lite@0.0.1 typeorm
> ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli migration:run -d ./typeOrm.config.ts

Error during migration run:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:120:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'postgres'
}


And Here is My docker compose
services:
  wemacc:
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth-gateway/Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: npm run start:dev wemacc
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - ./apps/wemacc/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - auth-gateway
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  auth-gateway:
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth-gateway/Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: npm run start:dev auth-gateway
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    env_file:
      - ./apps/auth-gateway/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=core_connect
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@pgadmin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}

I would like to know what I can do to fix this issue I have been stuck on it for over 24hours and I don't want to use synchronise:true in my TypeOrmm connection.
Let me know if there is any more file(s) I should share so anyone can be able to help me resolve this issue.

Where exactly are the migrations being run?

from my vs code terminal

If you're running migrations from a non-container context like an IDE terminal, then they won't be able to resolve the Docker-network hostnames.  How do you perform Django database migrations when using Docker-Compose? is a different tech stack, but it highlights several places where it makes sense in Docker to run migrations (as part of container startup, via docker-compose run).
